# C++: Divisão de vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++

Estou fazendo uma classe numérica dinâmica, armazenando o valor do número em um vetor de bytes. Fiz as funções de soma, subtração e multiplicação do mesmo jeito que se aprende na escola, porém isso não pode ser aplicado na divisão. Qual a maneira certa de fazer?

```
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long ulong;

class Num
{
private:
    vector<uchar> x;
    ...
public:
    ...
    Num(vector<uchar> other)
    {
        if(other.size() > 8) other.resize(8);

        while(!other.empty() && other[other.size() - 1] == 0)
            other.pop_back();

        x = other;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return x.size();
    }
    ...
    friend Num operator+(Num l, const Num& rhs)
    {
        Num r = rhs;
        vector<uchar> res (l.x);
        vector<uchar> mod (1, 0);

        while(r.size() < res.size()) r.x.push_back(0);
        while(r.size() > res.size()) res.push_back(0);

        for(uchar i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
        {
            mod.push_back((ushort)res[i] + (ushort)r.x[i] > 0xff);
            res[i] += r.x[i];
        }

        Num nmod = mod;
        if(nmod.size() > 0) return (Num(res) + nmod);
        return Num(res);
    }
    friend Num operator-(Num l, const Num& rhs)
    {
        Num r = rhs;
        vector<uchar> res (l.x);
        vector<uchar> mod (1, 0);

        while(r.size() < res.size()) r.x.push_back(0);
        while(r.size() > res.size()) res.push_back(0);

        for(uchar i = 0; i < res.size(); i++)
        {
            mod.push_back(res[i] < r.x[i]);
            res[i] -= r.x[i];
        }

        Num nmod = mod;
        if(nmod.size() > 0) return (Num(res) - nmod);
        return Num(res);
    }

    Num& operator+=(const Num& r)
    {
        Num res = *this + r;
        *this = res;
        return *this;
    }
    Num& operator-=(const Num& r)
    {
        Num res = *this - r;
        *this = res;
        return *this;
    }

    friend Num operator*(Num l, const Num& rhs)
    {
        Num r = rhs;
        Num res;

        for(uchar i = 0; i < r.size(); i++)
        {
            vector<uchar> temp(i, 0);
            vector<uchar> mod(i + 1, 0);

            for(uchar j = 0; j < l.size(); j++)
            {
                ushort v = l.x[j] * r.x[i];
                temp.push_back(v % 256);
                mod.push_back(v / 256);
            }

            res += Num(temp) + Num(mod);
        }
        return res;
    }
    ...
};
```

As operações que fiz são iguais as que se aprende na escola considerando cada `uchar` do vetor como se fosse um algarismo com base 256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode sim implementar algoritmos aprendidos na escola. Mas no seu caso você quer fazer uma adaptação onde se trabalha com cada `uchar` do vetor sendo um algarismo de base 256, correto? Além disso, deve-se definir o tipo de divisão que será feita. Vamos assumir que é divisão euclidiana de números positivos.

A imagem a seguir servirá de guia. Ela apresenta como exemplo a divisão de dois números, um dividendo com seis algarismos (recomenda-se que o de maior magnitude não seja zero) dividido por um divisor de quatro (o de maior magnitude simplesmente não pode ser zero). A imagem apenas apresenta as posições dos algarismos operados para ficar mais claro como se realizam as operações em termos de etapas.

A imagem não apresenta algarismos de exemplo porque isso depende da base em que se trabalha e a explicação será dada independentemente da base. A questão é que a lógica independe da base numérica, portanto vale para sistema binário, octal, decimal, hexadecimal, base 256, etc, assim se atentando apenas às casas de cada dígito e às restrições (por exemplo, em base octal os dígitos vão de 0 a 7 e o que exceder desses limites gera carry).

[image: Casas de algarismos em processo de divisão euclidiana.]
O algoritmo consiste em repetidamente encontrar um dígito correto do quociente, dos dígitos de maior magnitude aos de menor, e atualizar um número temporário até que o quociente esteja completo, quando então o número temporário final é o resto. Cada repetição é realizada considerando o emparelhamento de algarismos.

No início, o número temporário é igual ao dividendo. A cada repetição, trabalha-se com os dígitos de maior magnitude do temporário. A quantidade de dígitos do temporário trabalhados no primeiro ciclo é o mesmo número de dígitos do divisor (no exemplo, apenas os quatro algarismos mais avançados são trabalhados) e nos seguintes libera-se mais um algarismo do temporário para trabalhar neles. Essas repetições ocorrem até não sobrar mais algarismos no número temporário para incluir ao final do ciclo, sendo este portanto o último.

Esse trabalho consiste em:
(1) investigar qual é o maior algarismo (na base utilizada) cujo produto dele com o divisor é menor ou igual ao trecho trabalhado do número temporário;
(2) setar o algarismo do quociente com esse número;
(3) setar aqueles algarismos temporários com a subtração deles com o produto que foi calculado em (1).

Portanto é necessário um procedimento que compara se um número é menor ou igual a outro (para o passo (1)), outro que calcula multiplicação (para o passo (1)) e outro ainda que calcula subtração (para o passo (3)). É lógico que utilizar o comparador e o produto no procedimento (1), este programado a parte ao invés de calculá-lo inline, na busca do algarismo correto é uma medida adequada. Há várias formas de encontrar esse máximo, fica a sua escolha. No seu lugar eu trabalharia em binário mas refletido em base 256, assim.

Chamando o temporário de "Tmp1", usaria outro temporário "Tmp2" (para valores de potência de 2) e mais um "Tmp3" (para produto "Tmp2*Divisor").

(a) Atribuir, por hora, "DígitoDoQuociente=0";

(b) Repetidamente trabalhar com "Tmp2=128", depois "Tmp2=64", "Tmp=32", daí em diante até o último "Tmp2=1" (repare que dá para calcular deslocando bits para ganhar desempenho):

(b.1) Calcular "Tmp3=Tmp2*Divisor" (dá para calcular deslocando bits;

(b.2) Se "Tmp3<=Tmp1", calcular "DígitoDoQuociente=DígitoDoeQuociente+Tmp2";

(b.3) Se "Tmp3<=Tmp1", calcular "Tmp1 = Tmp1-Tmp3".

Comment: Como o resto pode ser negativo?

Comment: De qualquer forma, a divisão será inteira euclidiana, pois essa classe não possui assinatura e nem algarismos decimais (ponto flutuante)

Comment: A divisão inteira na computação é diferente da divisão inteira na matemática. Se, por exemplo, você escreve em C++ a expressão constante ((-99)%(15)), o valor da expressão será -9 quando na verdade o resto da divisão euclidiana retorna 6 (15-9). É porque ((99)%(15)) é 9, aí se o dividendo (no caso 99) trocar de sinal, na computação o resto (no caso 9) troca de sinal também.

Comment: Qual método você recomenda para o passo (1)? Sou novo nisso, só consigo pensar em usar um `for` ou um `while`, mas eu vou ter com isso 256^8-1 repetições no pior caso (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF / 1)

Comment: Vou complementar no final da minha resposta.